# Image Data to Blob from XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, image, image-processing, xmlhttprequest

I am making an `XMLHttpRequest`:

```
request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', modifiedImageUrl, true);
request.onreadystatechange = ->
    if request.readyState == 4
        if request.status == 200
            blob = new Blob([request.response], { type: 'image/jpeg' })
request.send(null);
```

(Please excuse my coffeescript). I would like to create a `Blob` from the retrieved image, but am not getting any data in my blob besides the size and type:

```
Blob
    size: 88804
    type: "image/jpeg"
    > __proto__: Object
```

Looking at `request.response`:

[image: Response (screenshot of data displayed as text)]

What is this format? How can I go about converting this to a `Blob` that has more information than just the size?

Answer (score 1):

The blob has the data in it, you just can't view it like that.
Also if you didn't set your response type to arraybuffer(or blob) you image data is going to get corrupted.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So request.responseType = 'blob' after request.open? What dictates the distinction between usage of arraybuffer or blob?

Comment: The default type is text i.e. a js string which cannot hold arbitrary binary data, using blob or array buffer will allow your response to be the data you expect. Either one is fine, if you use blob request.response  will be a blob so you don't have to create one.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the data is being decoded as ASCII when you don't specify a responseType. So for every character greater than 127, you get a 253, thus the image gets corrupted. To avoid this add `overrideMimeType` with `charset=x-user-defined`.

```
request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.overrideMimeType('image/gif; charset=x-user-defined');
request.open('GET', modifiedImageUrl, true);
request.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if (request.readyState == 4)
        if (request.status == 200)
            blob =  = new Blob([Uint8Array.from(request.response, c => c.charCodeAt(0)).buffer], { type: "image/gif" });

}
request.send(null);
```